Usual Arithmetic Conversion in Arithmetic Operation
I am currently learning about type conversion in C, and I came across the concept of Usual Arithmetic Conversions in implicit type conversion.
Implicit type conversion, in which the C compiler automatically converts the type without the programmer's involvement, is what I have understood: if the type is narrow, it is promoted to the wider type.
First Experiment with Relational Operators
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){

    unsigned long int a  = 8888;
    unsigned long int c = 0;
    signed int b = -1;

    if(a > b){
        c = 10;
    }else {
        c = 7;
    }
    
    printf("C value is %lu\n",c);
    
}

In the code provided, the value of c ends up being 7 even though mathematically, a is larger than b, and we would expect c to be 10.

Why doesn't this happen?
This lies in the type promotion. Because here, the signed type is a smaller type (Narrow) compared to the unsigned type,  which is larger (wider), so it gets promoted => which causes the type promotion, so the signed type is converted to unsigned type implicitly, which means now b is 2^32 around 4 billion so that the if statement is false and the else is executed.
For relational operators, it is ok.
Second Experiment with Arithmetic Operators
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){

    unsigned long int a  = 8888;
    unsigned long int c;
    signed int b = -1;

    c = b + a;
    
    printf("C value is %lu\n",c);
    
}


For me this was happen

Why does the relational operator (a > b) not behave as I expected? Specifically, why does the comparison seem to treat -1 (signed) as a large number instead of a small one?

For this relational operator, implicit conversion happens means why don't they happen for the arithmetic operation?

In the arithmetic operation b + a, why do I get a result of 8887 instead of a larger number like 4294976184? Does this involve overflow, or is it another issue with how the signed value is promoted?


Please don't post images of text. Copy-paste all text as text into your questions.

unsigned arithmetic in 32 bits is like regular school positive arithmetic modulus 4294967296. Or 8888 + -1/*converted*/ = (8888 + 4294967295) mod 4294967296 = 4294976183 mod 4294967296 = 8887



… Specifically, why does the comparison seem to treat -1 (signed) as a large number instead of a small one?


Arithmetic in C largely follows what is available in processors. Processors generally have instructions to work with numbers in the same format. For example, there may be an instruction to add two eight-bit signed integers, another instruction to add two 16-bit signed integers, another to add two 32-bit signed integers, and similarly instructions for multiplying, dividing, and comparing numbers. (Sometimes these instructions take advantage of mathematical properties so that one instruction can serve multiple purposes. For example, adding two eight-bit numbers can be performed by adding two 32-bit numbers but ignoring the top 24 bits. But this is another topic.)
Processors generally do not have an instruction that compares a 32-bit unsigned integer to an eight-bit signed integer. Adding such an instruction would require adding more wires and switches to the processor, and that is not worthwhile for an operation that would be rarely used. Without a specific instruction for this, C could provide the comparison operation, but it would have to use multiple instructions. We could do it by comparing the eight-bit integer to zero. If it is less than zero, it is also less than the unsigned integer. Otherwise, we could then convert the eight-bit integer to a 32-bit unsigned integer (just by putting it in a larger register, with the high 24 bits set to zero) and using the instruction to compare two 32-bit unsigned integers.
But that is more work than most comparisons. C is largely designed to facilitate and encourage efficient code. The rules about arithmetic conversions in C expressions were designed to work with typical processors. Programmers who want to evaluate expressions differently need to write their own code for that.


In the arithmetic operation b + a, why do I get a result of 8887 instead of a larger number like 4294976184? Does this involve overflow, or is it another issue with how the signed value is promoted?


For illustration, I will assume your C implementation uses 32 bits for unsigned long int. When you add the unsigned long int value 8888 (22B816 in hexadecimal) and the signed int value −1, the signed int is converted to unsigned long int, which produces 4,294,967,295 (FFFFFFFF16). That is because conversion to a 32-bit unsigned integer is defined to wrap modulo 232 = 4,294,967,296.
Adding 22B816 and FFFFFFFF16 is mathematically 1000022B716, but that is 33 bits. Unsigned integer arithmetic is also defined to wrap, so that 232 bit is eliminated, and the result is 000022B716 = 8887.

As you presume, the operands of < and + undergo type conversion. Specifically, they undergo the usual arithmetic conversions.[1]
When performing the usual arithmetic conversions for an unsigned long int (a) and a signed int (b), the signed int (b) is converted to an unsigned long int.[C23 §6.3.2.8]
To convert -1 to an unsigned long int, we repeatedly add or subtract ULONG_MAX+1 (using arithmetic rules, not C rules) until we get a result in range.[C23 §6.3.1.3 ¶2][2] This produces ULONG_MAX.
a > b
This compares the converted values. 8888 is a lot smaller than ULONG_MAX. Clearly false.
To get the desired result you can use b < 0 || a > b.
a + b
This sums the converted values. To be more specific, since these are unsigned integers, this sums the converted value, modulo the maximum value of the type plus one.[C23 §6.2.5 ¶11][3] So this produce ( 8888 + ULONG_MAX ) % ( ULONG_MAX + 1 ) (using arithmetic rules, not C rules), or 8887.


C23 §6.3.2.8 [...] Otherwise, if the operand that has unsigned integer type has rank greater or equal to the rank of the type of the other operand, then the operand with signed integer type is converted to the type of the operand with unsigned integer type. [...]


C23 §6.3.2.3 ¶2 Otherwise, if the new type is unsigned, the value is converted by repeatedly adding or subtracting one more than the maximum value that can be represented in the new type until the value is in the range of the new type.


C23 §6.2.5 ¶11 The range of nonnegative values of a signed integer type is a subrange of the corresponding unsigned integer type, and the representation of the same value in each type is the same. The range of representable values for the unsigned type is 0 to 2N − 1 (inclusive). A computation involving unsigned operands can never produce an overflow, because arithmetic for the unsigned type is performed modulo 2N.



Processors are typically unable to perform operations on operands of different types.
This amounts to a sign-extension operation on a two's complement machine.
This amounts to simply dropping the high-significance bits that don't fit.


ISO/IEC 9899:2024 was published in late October 2024. There are drafts for the C23 standard available as N3096 and N3220. However, there are sections missing from both drafts compared to the released C23 standard. Note that the drafts use §6.3.1.8 to identify §6.3.2.8 in the official standard (the standard has §6.3.1 Introduction which the drafts do not have).

@Jonathan Leffler, That sucks. Fixed.


Implicit type conversion which c complier automically convert the type without programmers involed in that what I have understand is if type is narrow it promoted to the wider type

Yes, that is a reasonable, albeit rough, summary of the usual arithmetic conversions.  C does not do any integer arithmetic with types narrower than int,* and it does not directly evaluate expressions with mixed arithmetic operand types.  To achieve that, operand values are automatically converted as needed so that they have the same type (for binary operations), at least as wide as int if it is an integer type.  The conversions are structured to preserve value inasmuch as is possible, but there are two irreconcilable challenges to that:

If one of the original types is a floating-point type and the other is an integer type, then it is often the case that the FP type has a wider range, but the integer type has more precision.  A floating-point type is chosen in these cases to best preserve the magnitude of each operand, but that may lose precision.

If the operands have (promoted) integer type of differing signedness, with neither being able to represent all the values the other can represent, then the signed one is converted to unsigned. Converting an out-of-range value to an unsigned type is well defined in C, and it involves reducing the value modulo one more than the maximum value of the unsigned type.  This indeed means that small negative numbers get converted into large positive ones.




Why does the relational operator (a > b) not behave as I expected? Specifically, why does the comparison seem to treat -1 (signed) as a large number instead of a small one?


The operands of relational operators are subject to the usual arithmetic conversions.  Your particular operands have types unsigned long int and signed int, which falls into category (2) above.  The signed operand is converted to unsigned long int, producing in this case the maximum value of type unsigned long int.  This compares greater than the other operand (888UL).


In the arithmetic operation b + a, why do I get a result of 8887 instead of a larger number like 4294976184? Does this involve overflow, or is it another issue with how the signed value is promoted?


Yes, the true arithmetic sum of the converted operands is greater than the maximum value representable by type unsigned long int.  C specifies that same modulo conversion in this case, which has the result you observe.  It is not accidental that the result in this case is the same as the mathematical result of 8888 + -1: that it should be so follows from the way signed --> unsigned conversions are defined.

*Technically, of lower integer conversion rank than int.

Other answers have well address how the compare behaves contrary to OP's expectations.
Reference alternative
If OP still needed to compare 2 different types that may differ in sign-ness, without value change, like unsigned long and signed int over the full arithmetic range of both, one could code:
#include <limits.h>

// Return 1 if a > b.
// Return -1 if a < b.
// Return 0 if a == b.
int cmp_ul_i(unsigned long a, int b) {
  #if ULONG_MAX <= LLONG_MAX
    // Convert the unsigned type to a wider signed type that encompasses both ranges.
    return ((long long)a > b) - ((long long)a < b);
  #else
    if (b < 0) {
      return 1;  // All `a` are more than a negative `b`.
    }
    // At this point `b` is entirely in the range of `a`.
    // Use a cast to quiet warnings of comparing differing sign-ness.
    return (a > (unsigned)b) - (a < (unsigned)b);
    return (a > b) - (a < b);
  #endif
}

